# What are the key combinations for alphabets ' ऋ ' and ' ॲ ' on Hindi Bolnagari keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I am using Hindi Bolnagri as an alternate keyboard layout. I wanted to type <kbd>ऋ</kbd> and <kbd>ॲ</kbd>.

Is there any key combination like there is for <kbd>क्ष</kbd> (kxS) and <kbd>ज्ञ</kbd> (jxY)? If not, can I do something to assign them at a third level.

I know we can press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> and then type <kbd>0972</kbd> for <kbd>ॲ</kbd> and <kbd>090b</kbd> for <kbd>ऋ</kbd>, but it is a pain to do this.

Also note: I am very new to Linux, so I am not familiar with things, so a step by step tutorial would be good for me.

Comment: No worries, I googled and found out a way on my own. Thanks to whoever spent time trying to solve my problem.

Comment: Can I answer my own question so that anybody who reads this can benefit from it ??

Comment: [Of course](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)! Not only it is OK to answer your own question, it's in fact encouraged for that same reason you mentioned.

Comment: Please answer your own question and select it as the accepted answer by putting a green check mark on the left. This will help others find it.

Comment: @AJha You can now, as Dan said.

Answer (score 1):

For <kbd>ॲ</kbd> as in "कॲकोना" (*n.* a name in *Bengoli*), the combination would be <kbd>**o**</kbd><kbd>[image: image1]</kbd> i.e. for *कॲ* the combination would be <kbd>**k**</kbd><kbd>**o**</kbd><kbd>[image: image2]</kbd>, where<kbd>[image: image2]</kbd> is the accent grave key (the lower-case of <kbd>[image: image3]</kbd> key in my keyboard).

[image: keyboardLayout]

No idea for the <kbd>ऋ</kbd> combination (I'd use *रि*, if the grammar allows).

*Nepali* language too uses the *[devnagari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari)* script. Here's a snapshot of the keyboard layout:

[image: keyboardNepali]

---

*Useful link:*

- [Hold a key to temporarily switch keyboard layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414269/hold-a-key-to-temporarily-switch-keyboard-layout/418176#418176)

Answer (score 0):

**Hindi (Bolnagri)**

<kbd>Right Alt + a</kbd> => `अ`   **+**   <kbd>Shift+z</kbd> => `ॅ` = अॅ

although **Hindi (Wx)** keybaord have shortcut for ऋ

<kbd>`Right Alt + q`</kbd> ==> ऋ

Answer (score 0):

Right Alt + Shift + r => ऋ  - this is in Arch Linux Hindi Bolnagari
Right Alt + r => ऋ  - this is in Arch Linux Hindi KaGaPa Phonetic