# xdotool can't type "y"

Tags: 13.10, xdotool

For a small automation process I am using xdotool because I need my script to ssh into a virtual machine and execute commands there. After upgrading Ubuntu to 13.10, it seems like xdotool can't type `y` correctly anymore. Even a simple

```
xdotool type --clearmodifiers "y"
```

leads to `←` being typed. It seems to work just fine for characters other than `y`. I tried un- and reinstalling xdotool, but no success. Any ideas or suggestions on how to fix this?

I have xdotool with version 3.20130505.1 and am using a Dell Latitude E6530 with Ubuntu 13.10.

**Edit:** Output of `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.input-sources`:

```
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current uint32 0
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources per-window false
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources show-all-sources false
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources [('xkb', 'de')]
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options @as []
```

Comment: Have you tried any other desktop than Unity?

Comment: @DKBose Which version does your xdotool have? Mine is 3.20130505.1.

Comment: @Sneetsher No, I only tried it on this laptop. Since DK Bose tried it, apparently it's not a "everyone has it" problem.

Comment: @IngoBürk, yeah, I'm with you in that. But it may be a problem with your user settings. You may try also with new user.

Comment: @Sneetsher Oh, alright, sorry about that. I can definitely try using my guest user. It will have to wait a little bit, but I'll let you know as soon as tried it.

Comment: Something I noticed: If I switch to the English (rather than German) keyboard layout, it types both `y` and `z` just fine. Maybe this is a layout problem? However, the map Ubuntu shows for the German layout is fine…

Comment: Some more searching brought me to a working solution, I posted it as an answer. Thanks you guys for your help, though.

Comment: @IngoBürk, could you add to the question results of `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.input-sources`. It seems weird how `y` didn't work from unity `de` layout.

Comment: @Sneetsher I added the output.

Comment: Hmm `xkb` is there, no idea

Comment: I might try this again after a clean restart. Maybe it'll be different. That's gonna have to wait for a bit, though.

Comment: Just for completeness, after a restart without ever executing the `setxkbmap` command, the output is still the same. Also, using the guest user didn't change anything either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After determining that it's likely an issue with my German keyboard layout, I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/xdotool-users/E-6AXaNPIJ4) post with the recommendation to run

```
setxkbmap de
```

This seems to have fixed the issue for now.

Comment: Does it work well? As I experienced before `setxkbmap` doesn't work well with Unity layout switching (in Ubuntu 13.10/14.04). One of them will stop working.

Comment: It keeps working if I switch to English, but it stops working when switching back to German until I execute the command again. I caveat I can live with, I don't really ever switch layouts. If there's a better solution I definitely would like to know about it. :)

Comment: May the best thing available is to define layout toggle shortcut using `setxkbmap` and avoid using Unity ones (shortcuts or indicator). Example: `setxkbmap de,us -option grp:alt_shift_toggle` . To see all list of possible toggle combination `more /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst | grep grp:` . Another point if you want to use right or left ctrl or any key which have two see https://askubuntu.com/questions/414269/hold-a-key-to-temporarily-switch-keyboard-layout/418155#418155 you may need to modify `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` . Please, would you update answer after you tested it.

Comment: Since I don't really ever switch layouts this seems unnecessary for me, I just added the `setxkbmap` command to my automated script. Although it's useful information for people with the same problem.